# "search results" or "the search results"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Using articles is sometimes tricky. But I hope my understanding is improving with the great answers provided in this forum.

> Some students said that the Google search engine show xx in the search
>   results

Or,

> Some students said that the Google search engine show xx in search
>   results

Comment: Not your question, but "[search] engine" is singular, so it should be **shows**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with *the search results* because it’s ***the*** results **the** students got after entering a search query.

*Search results* is an abstract thing. You could hear a Googler lecturing on a complex process of generating *search results*. It’s general and contextless.

On the other hand, you browse through *the* result page. You see *the* search results.

Answer (score 0):

Example **"search results"**

```
 1. Write an evaluation of your search results.
 2. Your search results may vary..
```

Example **"The search results"**

```
 1. The search results and the ads are provided by Google.
 2. An explanation of the search results page is also provided.
```